# How to write junit testcase for Enum class

Tags: java, junit, enums

I have a Enum class like this    Ex:

```
public Enum MyActivity{    
    Catch(MyActivityGroup.ball),
    Throw(MyActivityGroup.helmet),
    Run(MyActivityGroup.single);

    private Enum MyActivityGroup{
       ball, helmet, single    
    }
}
```

How to write junit testcase class for this Enum class...?

Comment: What are you testing in junit?

Comment: Why do you want to write a test for that enum? There is nothing that should be tested ...

Comment: I need to write testcase for improving code coverage. While i check this class with sonar, it shows 0% unit test code coverage.

Comment: you need to configure sonar to ignore enums ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to be tested directly here. Probably the enum will be used in tests for other classes, which should be sufficient, since their existence is basically the only property of the Enums.